# SurveyJS embedding an Angular mat-select dropdown

Tags: angular-material, surveyjs

Hopefully someone can help me with this, suspect it's something basic I'm missing or not understanding.

I am trying to create custom question that incorporates a dropdown, populated with data from a service along with a button to create a new record.

I've used the examples in the docs from survey.js to create a custom question type which includes a simple mat-select element from angular material.  However the drop down doesn't appear.  The same element works fine when hosted outside a survey form.

I can provide an example but wanted to check if there is something obvious I'm missing before doing so.

Many thanks